# UserControl View in WPF MVVM Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have 2 UserControls in my MainWindow,one is with list of some names and the other is with a ListBox,TextBox and Button.The problem is when i run the application my mainwindow should be only with usercontrol1 and when i click on the name the usercontrol2 should open on my mainwindow.How can i achieve this,I'm new to this please help me

Comment: Set the Visibility property of the usercontrol2 To hidden, and then change when tou want it to appear again, more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx

Comment: Can you please post your xaml? You could do this: on the click event of the `userControl1` you change `userControl2.Visibility`. i think it should work.

Comment: well you could try the selectedValueChanged event to do what I told before http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that we could achieve your requirements. However, none of them have anything to do with `Visibility`, so perhaps your title could do with an edit?

Either way, I just answered a similar question just a few hours ago (always a good reason to search for an answer before you ask a question here) which would answer your question. Please take a look at the [WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views) question here on StackOverflow for an answer to your question.

While it might not answer all of your requirements, I trust that you can successfully apply it to your situation. However, if you need further help, just leave me a comment.

Comment: Did you *actually* read the answer? I didn't mention any `Button`. Either way, the answer would be the same, just call `ViewModel = new PersonViewModel();` from a data bound `SelectedItem` property or `SelectionChanged` event handler. You can call that line from wherever (that is in scope) and it will update the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle between hiding and making control using VisiblityProperty

Bind the properties VisiblityProperty and change its value depending on your logic

refer the below links

[Binding Visibility Converter in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720559/binding-visibility-converter-in-wpf-c-sharp)

http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/10/27/binding-converters---visibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: While the word `Visibility` *is* in the title of this question, I believe that it is slightly miss-leading. It would *not* be good to implement the user's requirements using the `Visibility` property because that would mean that all of the views would be taking up resources, even when not visible.