# MVVM: Raise PropertyChanged event for a DataContract class members

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, datacontract

I want to raise `PropertyChanged` event for a model with `DataContract`.
Initially I did this

```
[DataContract]
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember(Name="username")]
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Username;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }
}
```

which gave StackOverflow Exception beacause of Infinite Recursion.

So the solution I come up with is

```
[DataContract]
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="username")]
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Username;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }
}
```

Although this reflects the Username value to the control binding to "Username", this doesn't look the best way to me. Something is wrong. Also my model has approx 30-40 fields. Is this the right approach or can someone please suggest me a better way.

Thanks

Comment: That is generally the right way. Yes, there are slightly fancier ways of raising notifications, but what you've done will work fine for now. You can get rid of the `this.` in front of the private member assignment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13720780/109702

Comment: There's no need for `_Username` to be a property; that should be a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be so tempted to use caller-member-name here (if it is in your target framework):

```
private string _username;
[DataMember(Name="username")]
public string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set { SetField(ref _username, value); }
}

private void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value,
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
{
    if(!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field,value))
    {
        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(memberName);
    }
}
```

If caller-member-name isn't supported:

```
[DataMember(Name="username")]
public string Username
{
    get { return this._Username; }
    set { SetField(ref _Username, value, "Username"); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. [CallerMemberName] isn't supported in windows-phone.

Comment: @PratPor that actually depends on what compiler you're using; since it is **entirely** a compiler feature (not a framework feature), you can actually declare the attribute yourself (in the right namespace etc) - if you are using an up-to-date compiler, *it will work*

Answer (score 2):

```
[DataContract]
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Username;

    [DataMember(Name="username")]
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Username;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this._Username != value)
            {
                this._Username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }
}
```